# Convert TLE times (decimal days) to seconds after epoch

Tags: python, time

The standard two line element ([TLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set)) format contains times as 2-digit year plus decimal days, so `16012.375` would be January 12, 2016 at 09:00. Using python's `time` or `datatime` modules, how can I convert this to seconds after epoch? I think I should use structured time but I am not sure how.  `seconds_of` is a fictitious function - need to replace with something real.

EDIT: It will be most helpful if the answer is long (verbose) - like *one step per line* or so, so I can understand what is happening.

EDIT 2: After seeing the comments from @J.F.Sebastian I looked at the link for TLE and found it nowhere states "UTC". So I should point out the initial information and final information are UTC. There is *no reference to local time, time zone, or system time.*

e.g.

```
tim = "16012.375"

year = 2000 + int(tim[0:2])
decimal_days = float(tim[2:])

print year, decimal_days

2016, 12.375

# seconds_of is a fictitious function - need to replace with something real
seconds_after_epoch = seconds_of(2016,1,1) + (3600. * 24.) * decimal_days
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to get `datetime` object given `year` and `decimal_days`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> year = 2016
>>> decimal_days = 12.375
>>> datetime(year, 1, 1) + timedelta(decimal_days - 1)
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 12, 9, 0)
```

How to convert the `datetime` object into "seconds since epoch" depends on the timezone (local, utc, etc). See [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279) e.g., if your input is in UTC then it is simple to get "seconds since the Epoch":

```
>>> utc_time = datetime(2016, 1, 12, 9, 0)
>>> (utc_time - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
1452589200.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I've just seen this now. In this case I'm only converting the format of a UTC value, so I can use `time.mktime(timetuple)`  I've just asked a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35238827/3904031)

Comment: @uhoh the post linked in my answer says explicitly that you should NOT use `mktime()` with UTC time. Follow the link.

Comment: Thanks again. Could you narrow down to which of the seven answers you are referring? That will be helpful to future readers of this question also.

Comment: @uhoh : I'm referring to the accepted most-upvoted answer at the very top with my name on it.

Comment: OK, [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/3904031) doesn't seem to be accepted anymore. Honestly it is way too long and complicated for me to understand that explanation of why not to use `mktime()` in my situation (UTC -> UTC). It has a bug? Would you consider telling me how TO do this then (see title of my question above)?

Comment: See EDIT 2 - I'm surprised to see that the link *does not make it clear* that the TLE is UTC. I've made that clear in my other question but not here.

Comment: @uhoh: I've added the explicit formula on how to get "seconds since the Epoch" from UTC time. It is not a  bug in `mktime()`. `mktime()` accepts **local** time (and therefore you should not use it with **UTC** time unless your local timezone is UTC). [@Ali SAID OMAR's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34850037/4279) is wrong because it uses `mktime()`.

Comment: Ah - I like that! Yes indeed that also *looks* right. Thank you for your persistence and help. I will delete the follow-up question, since your solution preserves the microseconds. For example with `tim = "16012.1111111"` as input, your solution gives `1452566399.99904`

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this [EDIT according to the comments].

```
import datetime
import time
# get year 2 digit and floating seconds days 
y_d, nbs = "16012.375".split('.') 

# parse to datetime (since midnight and add the seconds) %j Day of the year as a zero-padded decimal number.
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(y_d, "%y%j") + datetime.timedelta(seconds=float("." + nbs) * 24 * 60 * 60)
# 1.0 => 1 day
# from time tuple get epoch time. 
time.mktime(d.timetuple())

#1481896800.0
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for adding the explanations as well.

Comment: Right idea, but shouldn't it be `strptime(y_d, "%y%j")`? According to the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) `%j` represents day of the year as a 0-padded decimal. For the `timedelta`, shouldn't it be `seconds = float("."+nbs)*24*60*60`?

Comment: OK I'm at a real computer now. Indeed @mtrw, `print d` returns `datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 16, 15, 0)` which is not right. It's most helpful to me if we do this one step at a time per line - also helps debugging.

Comment: float("."nbs) is exactly the same than float("." + "375")

Comment: fyi I've just asked a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35238827/3904031)