# How to add JulianDate objects or offsets in Skyfield

Tags: julian-date, skyfield

The `JulianDate` object in [Skyfield](http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) is a handy way to quickly produce and hold a set of time values in Julian Days, and pass them to Skyfield's `at()` method to calculate astronomical positions in various coordinates. (see an [example script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35358401/3904031))

However, I can't seem to find an `add` or `offset` method so that I can add a time offset or an iterable of offsets to a `JulianDate` object. I always seem to [struggle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34910712/3904031) with dates and times.

Here is a very simple, abstracted example. I generate `jd60` which is offset from an arbitrary `jd0` by 60 days. As a simple check I calculate the position of the earth at the two times and make sure it moves by about 60 degrees.

```
from skyfield.api import load, JulianDate
import numpy as np

data  = load('de421.bsp')
earth = data['earth']
```

Start with an arbitrary t_zero:

```
jd0 = JulianDate(utc=(2016, 1, 17.4329, 22.8, 4, 39.3))   # (y, m, d, h, m, s)
```

Now, make a second JulianDate object offset by 60 days

This works:

```
tim = list(jd0.tt_tuple())
tim[2] += 60   # add 60 days (~1/6 of a year)

jd60 = JulianDate(utc=tuple(tim))
```

**But, what I would like is something like:**

```
jd60 = jd0.add(delta_utc=(0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0)) # ficticious method
```

Now calculate the positions and find the approximate angle, just to see that it worked.

```
p0  = earth.at(jd0).position.km
p60 = earth.at(jd60).position.km

dot = (p0*p60).sum()

cos_theta = dot / np.sqrt( (p0**2).sum() * (p61**2).sum() )

print (180./np.pi) * np.arccos(cos_theta)
print "should be roughly 60 degrees"
```

gives

```
60.6215331601
should be roughly 60 degrees
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference [here](http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/time.html#utc-and-your-timezone),

My solution is as follows:

```py
from skyfield.api import load
import numpy as np
    
data  = load('de421.bsp')
earth = data['earth']
    
ts=load.timescale()
t=ts.utc(2016, 1, np.linspace(17.4329,77.4329,61), 22.8, 4, 39.3)
    
p=earth.at(t)
    
p0  = p.position.au[:,0]
p60 = p.position.au[:,60]
    
dot = (p0*p60).sum()
    
cos_theta = dot / np.sqrt( (p0**2).sum() * (p60**2).sum() )
    
print((180./np.pi) * np.arccos(cos_theta))
print("should be roughly 60 degrees")
```

Comment: Excellent! The question was written back in February before the `.timescale()` method existed. Nice catch!